# Network diagrams for ServiceBus for Windows 1.1

Tags: azureservicebus

We are looking for network diagrams for ServiceBus for Windows 1.1 in a load balanced env (using f5) after applying the sbfarm cmdlets described in this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/feseca/2016/09/13/considerations-while-planning-high-availability-for-windows-service-bus/

Any link or other help much appreciated!

(Find no better tag than azureservicebus although not identical).

Answer (score 0):

My team owns Service Bus. I don’t think I understand what information you are specifically looking for, John. But if the information is not already on the site, it will not be added at this point.

Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 goes out of mainstream support on 9th of January 2018 as [per the lifecycle policy published at release](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Service%20Bus%20for%20Windows%20Server).

We also published a [reminder about this on the Azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/collaboration-and-federation-azure-service-bus-messaging-on-premises-futures/) earlier this year.

The product and documentation are frozen and we are not providing any further adoption help for Service Bus standalone because of the upcoming EOL deadline.

If you are deploying the product for use with Sharepoint, my recommendation is to file a service request with Office related to Sharepoint deployment, and discuss guidance in that context, because the resulting application topology will obviously include the web farm and workflow manager.